# Large Table Select and Insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I haven't been able to find anything that solves this really, though I have found many things that seem to point in the right direction.

I have a table with ~4.7 Million records in it. This table also has ~319 columns. Of all of these ~319 columns, there are 16 that I am interested in, and I want to put them into another table that is just 2 columns. Now basically how this is set is that column "A" is just an ID and columns 1-15 are codes. None of the columns are grouped either (not sure if that matters).

I have tried things like:

```
Insert Into NewTable(ID,Profession)
 Select ID, ProCode1 From OriginalTable WHERE ProCode1 > ''
 UNION
 Select ID, ProCode2 From OriginalTable WHERE ProCode2 > ''
```

And so on. This didn't seem to do anything at all and I let it go for ~ 20 minutes.

Now I can get a small result doing the same but dropping the union and using a  `TOP (1000)`  statement, however even that will never work.

So the question is what can I do to take this:

`ID|PID|blah|blah|blah|...|ProCode1|ProCode2|ProCode3|...|ProCode15|blah|...`

into:
 `ID|PID|ProCode|`

across all ~4.7 million rows without running:

```
Insert Into NewTable(PID,ProCode)
select PID, ProCode1 FROM OriginalTable WHERE ProCode1 > ''

Insert Into NewTable(PID, ProCode)
select PID, ProCode2 FROM Original Table WHERE ProCode2 > ''

Insert Into New Table(PID, ProCode)
Select PID, ProCode3 FROM Original Table WHERE ProCode3 > ''

...
...
...
```

EDIT: I forgot that a majority of the columns for `ProCodeX` are blank. All `ProCode1` rows are occupied, but that becomes exponentially less each increase (e.g. `ProCode2` is <50% occupied, `ProCode3` is <10% occupied)

Comment: Why are you using just `UNION` , it should be `UNION ALL` and using UNION ALL will make a huge difference. Your last proposed method should work "Separate inserts for all the 16 columns with PID column", Separate all the inserts with the Key word `GO`.... And if it is taking time be patient 4.7 million rows are not really a small number , also you are inserting 4.7 x 16 almost 75 million rows , it will take time :)

Comment: Thanks, I will try the `UNION ALL` also I did make a change to the above because I forgot something crucial. :)

Comment: @kyle_engineer What do you mean by `WHERE ProCode1 > ''`. Do you want to filter empty string

Comment: Yes. There are millions of blank cells in the various columns, so I need to strip those out. The idea is for each PID to correspond to a singular ProCode so that I can cross reference PID->ProCode and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Cross Apply` with `Table valued constructor` to unpivot the data instead of using different `UNION ALL`

```
Insert Into NewTable(PID,ProCode)
select PID, ProCode FROM OriginalTable
Cross apply
(
values(ProCode1),(ProCode2),(ProCode3),..(ProCode15)
) 
cs (ProCode)
Where ProCode <> ''
```

This will be much faster than the `UNION ALL` query since this will do single physical table hit.

Comment: 5.5 Million rows affected in 00:01:59! That was the way to go! Thanks @Fireblade